# Automatically restart stopped VM, Hyper-V

Tags: virtual-machine, restart, hyper-v

Very little experience of Hyper-V, but I'm sure this should be very simply accomplished.  I have a single VM running in Hyper-V.  If it fails (stops, reboots, powers down) for which ever reason, I would like Hyper-V to restart the VM.

Basically, I would like th VM to run at all times if possible, with minimal house keeping.

The server this is running on does nothing else.

Many thanks for your help!

LMT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is Microsoft not VMware ! Vmware esxi has `High Availability` and `Fault Tolerance` feature and are the most advance in market.

You can achieve that kind feature in Hyper-V but not exactly that, which is called `Failover Clustering` . But in order to achieve Failover Clustering your physical setup should have a cluster and shared storages.

For more information read about [Hyper-V and Failover Clustering](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732181%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) .

Now If you want to power on your VM programmatically then tell me I will post that in edit.

Comment: Thanks Reuben!  I can move to VMware if it gives me what I need.  I'm also interested in hearing about a programmatic solution, using hyper-v!